# Reading an array in Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help in reading the "users" array in my Firebase structure as shown below.

[image: Firebase structure]

I use the below function to grab the data from the channels table.

```
func observeChannels(channelId: String, onSuccess: @escaping (ChannelModel) -> Void) {
    DB_REF_CHANNELS.child(channelId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let channel = ChannelModel.transformChannel(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
            onSuccess(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

This is then passed to the ChannelModel class so I can grab each individual data.

```
class ChannelModel {
var channelId: String?
var channelName: String?
var ownerId: String?
var users: Dictionary<String, Any>? // Array of users }

extension ChannelModel {
static func transformChannel(dict: [String: Any], key: String) -> ChannelModel {
    let channel = ChannelModel()
    channel.channelId = key
    channel.channelName = dict["channelName"] as? String
    channel.ownerId = dict["ownerId"] as? String
    channel.users = dict["users"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
    return channel
}}
```

The observeChannels function is then called which returns me an object of all the channels.

```
observeChannels(channelId: channelId, onSuccess: { (channel) in
            self.channels.insert(channel, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            let user = channel.users!
            print(user)
        })
```

When I run the above function to get the users, my output is as follows:

```
["pZaEJ5aAAkR7WzgIJ4Wqf10jXot1": 1, "asdasldljAlsjkasldj": 1]
```

I was wondering how would I just get the key value - i.e:

```
["pZaEJ5aAAkR7WzgIJ4Wqf10jXot1", "asdasldljAlsjkasldj"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let usersDictionary = channel.users!
usersArray = Array(usersDictionary.keys)
print(usersArray)
```

instead of:

```
let user = channel.users!
print(user)
```

Comment: I tried the first option and it outputs:  `Keys(_variantBuffer: Swift._VariantDictionaryBuffer<Swift.String, Any>.native(Swift._NativeDictionaryBuffer<Swift.String, Any>(_storage: {
    asdasldljAlsjkasldj = 1;
    pZaEJ5aAAkR7WzgIJ4Wqf10jXot1 = 1;
})))`  whilst the second just returns nil

Comment: Try edited code i.e. usersArray = Array(usersDictionary.keys)